# Mono 2.10.5 Runtime error on Ubuntu 11.10 (possibly log4net?)

Tags: ubuntu, mono, log4net

I've install `mono-runtime` via `apt` in order to run my Mono console application on Ubuntu via SSH. However, when I run the command `mono myapp.exe`, It exits, with no message, and my program does nothing.

If I throw the `-v` switch to Mono, such as `mono -v myapp.exe`, I get about 10k lines of output (as expected, `-v` is verbose), with the first few lines being:

```
converting method System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string)
Method System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string) emitted at 0xb7052c28 to 0xb7052c4b (code length 35) [myapp.exe]
converting method (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object     (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
Method (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) emitted at 0xb7052c68 to 0xb7052cf6 (code length 142)     [myapp.exe]
converting method System.SystemException:.ctor (string)
```

[(Full Verbose Output)](http://seattle911.johnluetke.net/error.dump)

I read this as the runtime throwing an `OutOfMemory` exception, but the machine is under no intense load, has plenty of available RAM, and is running nothing other that system processes.

I've removed and reinstalled Mono countless times, and have even run the executable on other machines perfectly fine.

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

EDIT:

Per @[lupus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27051/lupus)'s answer, here is a dump of log4net's internal happenings. I don't see anything wrong with it:

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a]. Loaded from     [/mnt/ebs/911dispatch/scrapers/WA/Seattle/log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime [4.0.30319.1] on Unix 3.0.0.12)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Seattle911.Backend.Scraper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.Backend.Scraper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [/mnt/ebs/911dispatch/scrapers/WA/Seattle/Seattle911.Backend.Scraper.exe]
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.Backend.Scraper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.Backend.Scraper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Seattle911.DAL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.DAL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [/mnt/ebs/911dispatch/scrapers/WA/Seattle/Seattle911.DAL.dll]
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.DAL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [Seattle911.DAL, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists,     using repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [log4net-default-repository]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a log framework that will call Environment.Exit on fatal errors (this seems to be a connection error to the postgres database, maybe incorrect address/port or misconfigured server?).

You should configure log4net to not do that or check where it puts the log for the exact error your application hit and correct it.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the symptoms being occurring on other systems as well? The log4net configuration file I'm using is the same on all the machines

Comment: The other server may have access to the database, while this one may not (the default install of postgres usually allows access only from localhost).

Answer (score 2):

The `OutOfMemoryException` you are seeing is **always** allocated when initializing the Mono runtime.

**Why ?** because if (and when) the `OutOfMemoryException` instance is needed it will be a bad time to try to allocate one :-)

IOW this is totally normal since it's simply cached to be used, if needed, later. Sadly it means that your *real* error is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, It hadn't even occurred to me about the pre-allocation.

I'll continue to scour through the output. If anyone else is curious, I've edited the question to include a dump of the output